# Outputting a single row in stored procedure (oracle)

Tags: oracle, procedure

I'm trying to follow the example at http://dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm

But when i however do

```
create or replace PROCEDURE age
is
declare
info movie%rowtype;
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable();
select * into info from movie where mo_id=1;

dbms_output.put_line('The name of the product is ' || info.mo_id);

END age;
```

/

It gives a couple of errors:

*Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.*

and

*Error(14,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge*

what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following, you do not need to have declare inside a procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE
age
is
info movie%rowtype;
BEGIN
--dbms_output.enable();
select * into info from movie where mo_id=1;

dbms_output.put_line('The name of the product is ' || info.mo_id);

END age;
/
```

and to execute the procedure you could do

```
exec age
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things in your code to take a look at:
First. As @Polppan has already mentioned, remove `DECLARE` keyword from your stored procedure. There is no need of it. You will need it however when you write anonymous PL/SQL block. Second. If you use `dbms_output.enable()` in your procedure then to display lines, I assume you are using sql*plus for this, you will need to invoke `dbms_output.get_lines()` otherwise it will not give you desired result. So to simplify that use `set serveroutput on` command of sql*plus to enable output. And do not mix `dbms_output.enable()` and `setserveroutput on` - use either of them. Not both. Here is an example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Print_data
  2  is
  3    l_var_1 varchar2(101);
  4  BEGIN
  5    select 'Some data'
  6      into l_var_1
  7      from dual;
  8    dbms_output.put_line(l_var_1);
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec print_data;

Some data

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL>
```